# Forward Class and Protocols in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, protocols, forward-declaration

I have two classes where both of them have protocols to be implemented.

Can I implement one of the class's protocol in to the other and vice versa?

Does this cause any run time error?

Comment: Do you mean you want both classes to share the exact same implementation of the protocol?

Comment: no, different implementation, but both classes implement protocol of one another.  It looks there is not run time error with it. but still it can't get in to the block:  if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(.....)])
        {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But, I dont suppose this is really necessary. Once you have a delegate implemented then you could send a message to the other class as it the same delegate object. I suppose a simple delegate relations as;

**Class A**

```
@protocol ClassAProtocol;
@interface ClassA:NSObject
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<ClassAProtocol> delegate;
@end
@protocol ClassAProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)classA:(ClassA*)classa didSomething:(id)object;
@end

@implementation ClassA
-(void)classAFinishedSomething{
    [self.delegate classA:self didSomething:nil];
    [(ClassB*)self.delegate doSomething];
}

@end
```

**Class B**

```
@interface ClassB : NSObject<ClassAProtocol>
-(void)doSomething;
@end
@implementation ClassB
-(void)doSomething{

} 
-(void)classA:(ClassA*)classa didSomething:(id)object{

}
@end
```

This will not create a circular reference between the two objects and keep the code clean I suppose. This logic is valid if the delegate is always class B and it respondsToSelector:, the one being sent as a message to class B. But, the above sample posted by matt is mode rigid if you want to have isolate the log between the classes and communicate via standard mechanism.

Comment: Yes this is right and I already use this flow. The issue is when I want to keep this as it is and define a delegate to Class B and implement it in Class A

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is cyclic dependencies. Forward declaring won't really help either as you'll just get the compiler warning you that it can't see the definitions of the protocols. There are two options:

#### Option 1

Split the protocols out into their own header files:

ClassA.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ClassBProtocol.h"

@interface ClassA : NSObject <ClassBProtocol>
@end
```

ClassB.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ClassAProtocol.h"

@interface ClassB : NSObject <ClassAProtocol>
@end
```

ClassAProtocol.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol ClassAProtocol <NSObject>
...
@end
```

ClassBProtocol.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol ClassBProtocol <NSObject>
...
@end
```

#### Option 2

If you don't care about declaring externally that you implement the protocols, then you could use the class continuation category:

ClassA.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ClassA : NSObject
@end
```

ClassA.m:

```
#import "ClassA.h"
#import "ClassB.h"

@implementation ClassA () <ClassBProtocol>
@end

@implementation ClassA
@end
```

ClassB.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ClassB : NSObject
@end
```

ClassB.m:

```
#import "ClassB.h"
#import "ClassA.h"

@implementation ClassB () <ClassAProtocol>
@end

@implementation ClassB
@end
```

Comment: As you point out also it looks there is no problem with what I did. But: ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(...)]) returns false

Comment: Well, did you implement the method? If so, it will return true. If you don't implement the method, it will return false.

Comment: I think the reason was that I didn't instantiate an object and set the delegate. And if I do that in both sides, it wont serve my porpoise since I cant instantiate both at the same time with out using a third class.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you need to reconsider your object graph. Perhaps post another question outlining really what you're trying to achieve? (PS: "Serve my porpoise" made me chuckle :-P).